# Python requests get: "Dynamic backend host not specified"

Tags: python, openssl, python-requests

I am trying to do a very simple https "get" method using python's requests package, and it seems to work, except that I get an error message from the host machine saying:

```
"Dynamic backend host not specified"
```

I don't know exactly what that means. Is there some parameter that needs to be set in the get method?

Comment: Can you post the line where you call get?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it turns out that it's a matter of setting up the headers correctly.

Adding

```
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json', 'accept':'application/json'}
```

fixed the problem.

The code for the working call:

```
r = requests.post(
    HELLO_WORLD_URL,
    cert = (os.path.join(CERT_DIR, "cert.pem"), os.path.join(CERT_DIR, "example-key.pem")),
    auth = (USER_ID, PASSWORD),
    headers = {'content-type': 'application/json', 'accept':'application/json'})
```