# What are possible causes of ErrorMessage: Dynamic Backend Host Not Specified?

Tags: java, ssl, curl, soap, client-server

There is not much on SO about what to do when you are seeing `<ErrorMessage>Dynamic backend host not specified</ErrorMessage>` except for [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34253933/python-requests-get-dynamic-backend-host-not-specified)

Hoping this will become a resource for other developers who face this issue, as well as answer my specific case.

I am trying to test that SOAP requests sent from my client (built from WSDL) can hit a server (generated from the same WSDL), the source code for which I have no access to or responsibility for.

Currently I am just `curl`-ing against the server's endpoint with my (client) certificates and some XML to POST:

```
 curl -X POST https://www.endpoint.com/service.svc:443 --cert     certificates.p12:password --cert-type pkcs12 -d ‘<example>Place Holder XML </example>’
```

(Can't include the actual curl request due to its confidential nature)

The server is responding with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ErrorMessage>Dynamic backend host not specified</ErrorMessage>
```

The other SO answer linked above suggests that this may be a result of not including the correct headers in my request. If this is the problem in my case, does anyone know why the lack of headers is the cause of trouble here? Are there other possible causes of this error that are the responsibility of the client? Could this be an error on the server?

Comment: Is this may help ? https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014798066#77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014798189

Comment: That link is not very helpful. It's not super clear what they are talking about relative to what I am working with. For example, to what is the asker adding var://service/routing-url ? It looks like they may be working server side

Comment: With your question, it's hard to tell what's the problem. Have you tried with SoapUI ? There is a freely version available and it's better than curl to test SOAP.

Comment: I have tried with SOAPUi, but I am also getting the ErrorMessage. The problem is that `<ErrorMessage>Dynamic backend host not specified</ErrorMessage>` is a very unhelpful message, and there doesn't seem to be any documentation on the internet that suggest the underlying cause. I am at least trying to narrow down if the problem is client side or if the server has not be set up correctly

Comment: If you get the message with soap, it's probably a server fault or a soap header that is missing. Also, check your certificate. Do you have any other code that you can check that is working with the service you try to call ?